# How do you convert a struct into a char array?

Tags: c, serialization, embedded, char, cdma

I am a little bit confused on how to convert a struct to a char[] in C.

My CDMA modem doesn't support sending variables - it only understands ASCII characters.  I need to do the conversion operation.

Let's say that I have an sMSG struct like this:

```
struct sMSG
{
    int a;
    int b[];
    char c[];
    double d;
    float f;
};
```

So, I have to make a string like `char str[] = "sMSG_converted_into_ASCII_chars";`

I'm wondering if somebody will help me out on this, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do they have to be `ASCII` or can they be `0-255` ? Also, use the real definition of your struct.

Comment: Okay, say the byte `240` appears somewhere in your structure. How will this be sent to the modem ?

Comment: Are the sender and receiver different kinds of machines (endian-ness, word size)? That is of paramount importance.

Comment: cnicular, cdma modem works like this:
to send 1234-> AT$TCPWRITE=31323334
so, instead 1234, i should have a structure.

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question 'who sends data to whom?'. What are the machines involved? What is the mode of communication?

Comment: cdma modem(3g-CC864 module) sends data to server, mode of communication is wireless.

Answer (score 5):

First you need to copy the data of the struct into a byte array

```
int len = sizeof(struct sMSG);
unsigned char * raw = malloc(len);
memcpy(raw, &msg, len);
```

Now use a function to convert the byte array into Base64 text or just hexadecimal representation (2 chars/byte). Since you use the embedded tag, the latter might be the easiest to implement.

```
#define TOHEX(x) (x > 9 ? (x - 10 + 'A') : (x + '0'));
char * text = malloc(2 * len + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    text[2 * i + 0] = TOHEX(raw[i] >> 4);
    text[2 * i + 1] = TOHEX(raw[i] & 0xF);
}
text[2 * len] = '\0';

free(raw);
free(text);
```

Comment: I was gonna say `sprintf` it into a large enough array, but this solution is better! The `sprintf` solution has a problem handling field separators.

Comment: will the data those arrays point to be copied using `memcpy` this way (or will rather the pointers be copied)?

Comment: whether this 'just works' really depends on who 'sends' messages to whom, what the sizes of different data types are, endian-ness, etc etc. You can't just read this on a different machine and 'memcpy' it back into the right structure.

Comment: @ArjunShankar: that's correct, especially floats and double could even raise more trouble (if both platforms use a different notation)

Comment: This assumes (BIG ASSUMPTION) that there are no empty bytes in the data structure that you are memcpy'ing.  If the data elements are not assigned to a single contiguous set of memory locations then you will have extra padding bytes in the transmitted data.  The values in these locations are undefined and could have undesirable effects.